# Split text to column based on semicolon as delimited with column header inserts new column in-between

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA Macro. I am trying to create a code that converts "Text to column" identifying semicolon as delimited. There is data in column has which has 1 values with ; as separator in between.

[![Actual Data][1]][1]

Now I want the macro to covert column b data text to column those Y Y should be in different column after text to column the new column name should be KPI wherein new column KPI should insert in-between Band C column the column C named SSO should push further columns....

Desired output as follows.

[![Desired Output][2]][2]

[![MY Codes is not working][3]][3]

```
Sub TextToCol1()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exp")

With ws
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:A" & lRow).TextToColumns Semicolon:=True
    
    '.Range("A2:A" & lRow).TextToColumns ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Semicolon:=True, Space:=True 'Option 1
    '.Range("A2:B" & lRow).Value = Application.Trim(.Range("A2:B" & lRow)) 'Option 2
    
    .Cells(1, 2).insertcolumn = "KPI"

End With
  
End Sub
```

Kindly help to fix this issue.

Comment: You need to get rid of the `;` at the end of each value before the text to columns line.

Comment: How do I fix this I need to text to column this by inserting new column

Comment: Should 2 be the maximum of strings separated by ";" in a cell?

Comment: yes Y ; Y; should should be separated... The below answer macro is working but the pop up is coming please help on that I have pasted the output in image 5 last image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub TextToCol1()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exp")

With ws
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & lRow)
    For Each c In rng
        c = Trim(c)
        If Right(c, 1) = ";" Then c = Left(c, Len(c) - 1)
    Next c
    .Range("C:C").Columns(1).Insert
End With

With rng
    Application.DisplayAlerts=False 'Avoid false warning.
    .Columns.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True, Tab:=False, Space:=False, Comma:=False, Other:=False, Destination:=Range("$B$2:$C$"&lrow)  'Option 1
      Application.DisplayAlerts=True
     .Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 1).Value = "KPI"
    Set rng = .Resize(.Rows.Count, 2)
    For Each c In rng
        c = Trim(c)
    Next c
End With

Set rng = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It works but why it is giving pop already data is there I have pasted the pop up in question can u help fix that

Comment: I don't understand. What's wrong?

Comment: It appears that your data are different now. Initially it was just `Y; Y;` but now your data have words and spaces which obviously won't work with what I provided. The spaces in the words have become delimiters. It's important that you give a realistic description of your data because people will make assumptions based on that. Is there anything else we should know about your data structure?

Comment: yes there is macro first which replace the value to Y ;Y; then this macro is in place even after executing the macro in seq that pop up is coming

Comment: Ok, @Sandy Candy.,I've revised the code. Please mark as the solution if this fits your needs.

Comment: No I am still getting that pop up I will paste the output with todays date in question please guide.

Comment: I ran it without any warning messages using the data structure you provided. I can only guess you have more than two semicolons in the data you're using. Is that right?

Comment: yea I have replaced/removed that second ; still I get popup

Comment: If you say ok to the popup, where is the text splitting? At spaces? At letters?

Comment: If I hit ok it will split properly Pasting output in question

Comment: Strange. I had trouble with words being split in the middle when the pop up displayed but eventually configured settings to prevent that. I could turn off the warnings temporarily but am concerned this problem could occur again and overwrite something.

Comment: @Sandy Candy Okay. Try revised code.

Comment: its perfect now :)

Comment: Thanks @bugdrown much appreciate... Did you downrate this question.. This was very complex in my case and I got solution from you anyways all the best thanks.

Comment: No. That wasn't me. I don't know who did that.